# Circular references with containers and no weak_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

I know you should normally use shared_ptrs and weak_ptrs to make circular references solve themselves, but I found a different approach is working for my use-case and wanted to know if the following is ok or not and if it has any mayor disadvantages.

Basically, I implemented a doubly linked tree like so:

#### TreeNode.h

```
class TreeNode{
public:
    TreeNode();
    TreeNode(shared_ptr<TreeNode> parent);
    void addChild(TreeNode);
private:
    shared_ptr<TreeNode> parent_;
    vector<TreeNode> children_;
}
```

#### TreeNode.cpp

```
TreeNode::TreeNode() : 
    parent_(shared_ptr<TreeNode>(nullptr)),
    children_(vector<TreeNode>())
    {}

TreeNode::TreeNode(shared_ptr<TreeNode> parent) :
    parent_(parent),
    children_(vector<TreeNode>())
    {}

TreeNode::addChild(TreeNode child){
    child.parent_ = shared_ptr<TreeNode>(this);
    children_.push_back(child);
}
```

### My thoughs:

Because I know that a `TreeNode` always has to have a parent (except for the root, of course), the reference counting of `shared_ptr` seems irrelevant to me, as a parent will always outlive the pointer to it its children contain, so I might even use raw pointers at this point.
Also, I don't need pointers for the children because templating with incomplete types is allowed.

### My questions:

*1. Does this approach contradict any of the C++ conventions, should circular references always be done with shared and weak pointers no matter what?*

*2. Would it be dangerous to make parent a raw pointer, and if yes, why?*

Comment: Why is your logic to declare a parent and to add children decoupled of each other? Wouldn't it be better to make `addChild` private and call it in the constructor with parent? (something like `parent.addChild(this)`)

Comment: Regarding your main question: `shared_ptr` is wrong here. Its meaning doesn't fit, even if it is working if you're lucky. It means that all instances which reference the same object *own* that object (and no other context *owns* it too). The pointer without ownership is indeed the *raw pointer*, and I fail to see why you use a smart pointer at all. That being said, your code stops working if you add logic to modify the tree...

Comment: Adding to what @leemes said, you should *never* use smart pointers if the object isn't dynamically allocated with `new`. In this case the objects are owned by the vectors. Even though a vector uses `new` internally, it is still responsible for the lifetime and will call `delete` itself when necessary. Also be aware that adding to a vector will invalidate pointers into the vector.

Comment: Smart pointers define explicitly define *ownership*. The point of them is to know whose job it is to clean up the pointer (really). Using them makes it MUCH easier to make safe code because you can clearly define the lifetime of the dynamically allocated object. "would it be dangerous to make it a raw pointer" is kindof subjective, but the answer comes from the answer to "Can parent go out of scope (be cleaned up) before I get cleaned up? If that happens, what should I do?" and "Whose job is it to clean up parent?"

Comment: @leemes I want to be able to add and remove items dynamically, so no, `addChild` needs to be public.

Comment: To clarify, the problem everyone is having with this is that you can't make shared_ptr point to the instances in children with REALLY broken behavior. The reason? The following code block. `A a; {shared_ptr<A>(&a);} /*shared ptr goes out of scope, a is destroyed*/ a.foo();//oh noes!`

Comment: @leemes
But thanks for clarifying the ownership thing. It is quite hard to find non-biased information. Anywhere I see someone using raw pointers in a question on stackoverflow, there are dozens of comments about what kind of an idiot he is.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams
This makes so much sense now. I should really pick up a book on modern c++, wikibooks was a bad idea.

Comment: @iFreilicht no problem, but don't write off smart pointers completely. You can absolutely use smart pointers in this situation to enforce dynamic allocation and prevent unnecessary copies of the entire tree structure :-P

Comment: @iFreilicht My point was: Use the constructor to add a child OR use the addChild for that, but if you do the latter, also set the parentship. Do both in one function. Because it doesn't make sense to say A is a parent of B without also saying B is a child of A, does it? (and vice versa) Those relationships belong together (indeed, it's a single relationship, encoded in two places in your design, hence doubly linked, but they need to be *consistent*, which your code doesn't guarantee...)

Comment: @leemes oh right, I forgot to add that line in the `addChild` function. my real code was a bit more complex, I broke it down for this question for better readability. fixed now ;)